# How to get the index of duplicates in a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, for-loop, indexing

Python cannot seem to differentiate between duplicates of the same letter. For example:

```
word = "australia"
variable = "a"
for letter in word:
    if variable == letter:
        index = word.index( letter )
        print index
```

The result is:

```
0
0
0
```

While python knows that there are three occurrences of the letter "a" in the word "australia", it keeps returning the index of the first occurrence. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `word.index( letter )` will always return the index of the first occurance of `a` (which is 0) even though you're calling it multiple times in a loop.

Comment: @101 yes I understand this, but how can I change my code to get it to return the index of the other two occurrences also

Comment: Check the first answer in the above link, it gives what you're after.

Comment: @bariox: do read the documentation for methods you use. [`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) takes additional arguments, like `start`. `word.index(letter, index + 1)` would start searching from the last location. Or just *generate an index as you go along*; you have a loop, increment a counter in it. Or have Python do this for you with `enumerate()`.

Comment: @101 Thanks I was able to implement that post into my code